# ActiveMQ 5.4.2 queue class

Tags: java, queue, jms, activemq-classic

I am developing a messaging application and i have sent the data manually to the queue by creating a queue name="dataQueue" by accessing activemq from browser. Now i need to refer to that queue by using spring framework by the following code:

```
<bean id="dataQueue" class=" "></bean>
```

I am not able to find the class name for the queue in ActiveMQ.

Please tell what class should be there for specifying queue name. I am using activeMQ 5.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Look at this for instance: [Using Spring to Send JMS messages](http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com.es/2010/02/using-spring-jmstemplate-to-send-jms.html)